# ncurses transparent console background

Tags: c, ncurses

My console has transparency enabled, when I run other ncurses apps, I see the the background stays transparent. I'm trying to make my app keep the transparency and not apply a dark black opaque background.

This is what I'm doing so far

```
start_color();
init_pair(1, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);

attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
mvprintw(10,10, "Hello");

refresh();
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: FIXED: use_default_colors();

Comment: answering your own question is allowed and encouraged.  You might even get some rep out of it.

Comment: Repoened so that this can be answered properly.

Answer (score 8):

If your application calls [`use_default_colors`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/default_colors.3x.html), ncurses (and [NetBSD curses](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/curses_default_colors.3.html)) provide an extension based on ECMA-48 SGR 39 and 49 "default colors".  When you do this, ncurses refrains from explicitly coloring cells whose foreground and/or background color match its assumption about the terminal colors.

There is an additional function `assume_default_colors` which can be used to improve the default-colors feature where the terminal is (for example) using black text on a white background.

Most of the color-capable terminals you use support the SGR 39/49 codes, so the feature can be used most of the time.

Further reading:

- [Default Colors](http://invisible-island.net/ded/ded.html#influence_default_colors)