# C - Obtain neutral background with ncurses

Tags: c, linux, text, terminal, ncurses

In this simple program (written in C)

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 initscr();
 printw("line 1\n");
 printw("line 2\n");
 start_color();
 init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
 printw("line 3");
 getch();
 endwin();

 return 0;
}
```

a red text is printed on the screen over a black background. But when I run the program, the background is slightly brighter than the black background of the terminal, in Linux (Gnome terminal).

I don't want to set a background color over the default, black color of the terminal: I would like to keep the terminal background and to actually set the `ncurses` background as transparent.

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I tried to put the function `use_default_colors();` after `start_color();` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403399/ncurses-transparent-console-background) question, but it was not useful.

Comment: Of course there is, at least as far as the terminal emulation is concerned. You can find the corresponding ANSI-sequence here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code . You just need to set no background color at all / reset it. However, I don't know the corresponding macro name in ncurses, so that's not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `man init_pair`:

> As  an  extension, ncurses allows you to set color pair 0 via
>   the assume_default_colors routine, or to specify the use of default
>   colors (color number -1) if you first invoke the use_default_colors routine.

So, generally, if you want to use "default" color, use `-1` for color value, but make sure you've called `use_default_colors()` first.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 initscr();
 use_default_colors();
 printw("line 1\n");
 printw("line 2\n");
 start_color();
 init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, -1);
 printw("line 3");
 getch();
 endwin();

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a rule, you should also first check if the terminal supports colors using [`has_colors`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html).

Comment: @ThomasDickey correct, but I think this was more of an SSCCE app. It just showcases the fact that the terminal background changes, it doesn't even utilize the colorpair initialized. But that's fine :)

Comment: Also, the program as written does not show red on the last line (it lacks, for instance, `attrset`).

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, here is a corrected example starting with [@Pawel Veselov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622266/pawel-veselov)'s suggestion:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
 initscr();
 if (has_colors()) {
  use_default_colors();
  start_color();
  init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, -1);
 }
 printw("line 1\n");
 printw("line 2\n");
 attrset(COLOR_PAIR(1));
 printw("line 3");
 getch();
 endwin();

 return 0;
}
```

The last line should appear (for cooperating terminals) with red text on the terminal's default background color.  (To be pedantic, one could do the `attrset` only when `has_colors` is true...).

Running in white-on-black:

[image]

or in black-on-white:

[image]

uses the terminal's default background.  Without [`use_default_colors`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/default_colors.3x.html), ncurses assumes the terminal displays white-on-black (but then you can change *that* assumption using [`assume_default_colors`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/default_colors.3x.html)).

Comment: thank you, it was very useful anyway. What could be the behaviour of the program if `attrset` is used in a terminal which does not support colors?

Comment: In that case, no coloring (or adjustment for default colors) is done.